# TableView doesn't reload after change data and popViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, delegates, nsfetchedresultscontroller

In my app I am using  a NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate to reload a Tableview after to add new data, but this solution only works when I access the view in the first time.

If I delete the data and add it again the information doesn’t appear in the table view. For this I need to leave the view and access it again.

I've tried using Delegates and CallBack to reload the table view, but I was unsuccessful.

I figured out that cellForRowAt is not called after that new data is added as soon as the old data is delete. Although numberOfSections has been called.

I'm lost. Can someone help me?

[Here is the video with app behaviour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=frL9C0Tklqg&feature=youtu.be)

And here I show you some parts of my code:

**My NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate**

```
extension MeasureController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    switch type {
    case .insert:
        myTableView.insertSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
    case .delete:
        myTableView.deleteSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
    case .move:
        break
    case .update:
        myTableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
    @unknown default:
        fatalError()
    }
}


func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    myTableView.reloadData()
    myCollectionView.reloadData()
}

//Allow to show full section name in header.
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, sectionIndexTitleForSectionName sectionName: String) -> String? {
    return sectionName
}
```

}

**The viewWillAppear in my MeasureController that has the table view**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.fillDataInTheView()
    self.allMeasures = CoreDataManager.shared.loadAllMeasuresByAthlete(athlete: athleteToShow)

    //Get the last recorded date that has measures records
    if let allMeasures = self.allMeasures, let selectedDay = CoreDataManager.shared.getLastDayWithMeasures(measure: allMeasures) {
        self.selectedDay = selectedDay
    }

    if selectedDay != nil {
        if let measureByAthleteAndDay = CoreDataManager.shared.loadAllMeasuresByAthleteAndDay(athlete: athleteToShow, day: selectedDay) {
            self.measureByAthleteAndDay = measureByAthleteAndDay
        }

        do {
            try fetchedRCAllMeasuresByDay.performFetch()
        } catch let fetchedError {
            print("Error fetching Measures by Day:", fetchedError)
        }
    }

    do {
        try fetchedRCDay.performFetch()
    } catch let err {
        print(err)
    }

    if let lastEvaluation = getRecentDate() {
        lbEvaluationDate.text = "Última Avaliação: \(lastEvaluation.mediumDate())"
    } else {
        lbEvaluationDate.text = "Sem Avaliação Registrada"
    }

    self.myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

**Here is my myCollectioView for date data**

```
extension MeasureController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

// MARK: - Collection View Data Source

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let dates = fetchedRCDay.fetchedObjects else {return 0}
    return dates.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellCollectionViewID, for: indexPath) as! DateCollectionCell
    let day = fetchedRCDay.object(at: indexPath)
    if let date = day.title {
        cell.setupCell(date: date)
    }

    if day == selectedDay {
        cell.isSelected = true
    } else {
        cell.isSelected = false
    }

    cell.delegate = self

    return cell
}

// MARK: - Collection View Delegate

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.selectedCell(true, indexPath: indexPath)
    let day = fetchedRCDay.object(at: indexPath)
    self.alertToCreateEvaluation(day: day)
    myCollectionView.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.selectedCell(false, indexPath: indexPath)
    let day = fetchedRCDay.object(at: indexPath)
    if let date = day.title {
        lbEvaluationDate.text = "Data da Avaliação: \(date.mediumDate())"
    }
}

func hasMeasures(cell: DateCollectionCell, day: Day) {

    if day.allMeasures == nil {
        cell.ivIndicator.isHidden = true
    } else {
        cell.ivIndicator.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

}

***If you need more code to understand it better, let me know.***

Comment: If possible then post link of sharable demo project.

Comment: I found that cellForRowAt is not called after new data is added as soon as old data is deleted. Although numberOfSections has been called, the value is zero. But if you go back to the previous view and re-enter MeasureView, numberOfSections will have a correct value, in other words, numberOfSections will be nonzero.

Comment: So, Is it work now?

Comment: @Afonso is issue resoved ?

Comment: Where are your calls to `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`? Refer to Apple documentation for [NSFetcedResultsControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontrollerdelegate)

Comment: Hi guys, I still couldn't fix the issue. I've figured out the issue is in my fetchedResultsController or in its delegate. I'm trying new approach in my code and if I got success I let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... per the Apple Documentation for [`NSFetchedResultControllerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontrollerdelegate)...

Add a new instance method:

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {

    tableView.beginUpdates()
}
```

Change your existing `controllerDidChangeContent(_:)` instance method:

```
func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {

    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Leave out the calls to `.reloadData()` - these are "brute force" convenience methods that reload the entire table or collection view and make the use of the subtle FRC Delegate methods redundant.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried this approach before with no success. I've tried again but the behavior is the same. I don't know I the preblem is that I have a tableView and a conllectionView in the same viewcontroller with only one extension with NSFetchedResultsControllers for both.

Comment: Is the data source for each VC the same? Or in other words, does the collection view present the same data as the table view?